# External cache for WebView to load?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm using WebView in my application and I need to pre-cache some webpages for later use. Since   I want the caching process be less obnoxious, it have to be unnoticeable. So it's better to be implemented in a Service.

I don't know how to achieve this because WebView can only exist in an activity. Is there any method to cache webpages to local storage, and let WebView load it later? Or how can I realize the features with another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the Web pages don't call LocalStorage.clear before they exit the data should be available in a SQLite database.

If my memory is correct is under 4.03 the path is something like /data/data//app_database/localstorage/file__0.localstorage

As the local storage data is saved in a SQLite table called ItemTable you can read this data using the SQLite APIs (when in the same context).

So you could pre-populate the table from your service by inserts into this table.

Sorry to not paste any code - I dont have it with me but this will work - I have done it

Comment: First of all, thanks for this idea. Since I'm so unfledged in Android, I don't know how to implement this... Would you please tell me what method should I use to cache the contents?

Comment: first take a look at the SQLite classes http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html  - you can use these to read/write  the local storage DB.  As the ItemTable is just strings its simple to map these into your data structures. Also take a look at the sqlite tools   for example the firefox plugin - this will let you examine table schemas etc .

Answer (score 0):

Please, read this topic, you should find the answer there, it's explained in details:

http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm just a beginner to Android... It seems that the webpage is teaching us to cache webpages through webview itself, but what I need is to cache the contents through other methods or through webview silently. The provided webpage doesn't talk about this feature.